# Command not found for alias

Tags: apache2, bashrc, alias

I recently installed the `apache2` package using the Software Centre, I want to create an alias `apacheres` which will replace the more cumbersome command `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`.

I opened the `.bashrc` file in my home directory, and it contains the following lines:

```
# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

So I created a `.bash_aliases` file in my home directory, and added only this line:

`alias apacheres ='/etc/init.d/apache2 restart'`

When I started my terminal, I get this error message:

```
bash: alias: apacheres: not found
bash: alias: =/etc/init.d/apache2 restart: not found
```

The shell has obviously read the file, otherwise it wouldn't know of its existence. I have checked the directory path and I can find the file `apache2` there. ***What do I need to do to make this alias work?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the space before the `=` in the alias assignment

```
alias apacheres='/etc/init.d/apache2 restart'
```